# GREL: qq about Templating Export and Nulls (Open Refine)

Tags: openrefine, grel

There is some expression more elegant than this to avoid printing NULLs and words "NULL"?
By reading the Open Refine's docs https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/General-Refine-Expression-Language I have done this bellow, but feels odd and complex.

Cheers.

```
{
  "rows" : [
{{ if(isNull(cells["supplierID"].value),
"",
"      \"supplierID\" : " + jsonize(cells["supplierID"].value)

)}},

{{ if(or(isNull(cells["homePage"].value), cells["homePage"].value == "NULL"),
"",
"      \"homePage\" : " + jsonize(cells["homePage"].value)

)}}

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually I'd aim to make the column consistent (i.e. either contain a `null` value in all cases or the string "NULL" in all cases, but not a mix of these) before doing an export. So you could run a transform on the column first like:

```
if(value=="NULL",null, value)
```

If you were to do this first, then in the export template you can use:

```
forNonBlank(cells["homepage"].value,v,"      \"homePage\" : " + jsonize(v),"")
```

However, if you don't want to make this change in the data for some reason, you can achieve a slightly more elegant option than the one you have by using the 'coalesce' function (available from OpenRefine 3.0 onwards) which chooses the first non-null value from a list:

```
{{ if(coalesce(cells["homepage"].value,"NULL")=="NULL","","      \"homePage\" : " + jsonize(cells["homePage"].value)) }}
```

The coalesce will use the value of cells["homepage"].value if it is non-null, or fall back to using the string "NULL" if cells["homepage"].value *is* null. So this means that if you feed a cell with content string "NULL" or a cell that has `null` - the coalesce function outputs the string "NULL" in both cases - which means you then only have to check for the single condition.

coalesce is documented at https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL%20Other%20Functions

Comment: Yeah, I have used 'if(value == "NULL", "", "")' in the columns, but I wanted to know if there was something to "bulk" already in the export part. I was trying to use coalesce, but failed. Thanks. Do you know if there is some GREL course? The docs are fine, but use cases teaches more.

Comment: There are courses for OpenRefine but they inevitably don’t cover all aspects. See https://librarycarpentry.org/lc-open-refine/ https://datacarpentry.org/OpenRefine-ecology-lesson/ https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/cleaning-data-with-openrefine https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/fetch-and-parse-data-with-openrefine . There is also currently a rewrite of the user documentation underway with a focus on using clear examples which may help. The Recipes page on the current wiki is also often helpful for examples https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Recipes